# Get list and default value of columns of table with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I use the below code to get a list of columns in a table, and assign the default value to the protected var $attributes in a Laravel Model.

In this code, I use the DB function because I don't know how to achieve the same result with Eloquent.

**Model.php**

````
protected $attributes = [];

public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    $columns = DB::connection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableColumns('mailboxes');

    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        $name = $column->getName();
        $value = $column->getDefault();
        if (!is_null($value)) {
            $this->attributes[$name] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: I don't think there is any easier way to do this. The question to ask is, is it necessary. This will add an overhead to every model regardless of if you use it or not. If you were to set hard coded default attributes in the model, they will overwrite the database defaults anyway, making the database defaults redundant, unless you are also inserting records from a non-eloquent source.

Comment: Hi. I have seen that there are no problems or costs, since I am testing 10,000 items and it does not show.
The reality is that it is a softward and third parties and the table has more than 50 fields, to which I need to pass the default value. It seems more logical and useful, to automate this than to write in the resource de nova, each of the default values, and do its testing. In this way it is more global. Thank you.

Comment: if it is working fast enough for you, then there is no nothing more i can add, your code looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

If I’m fully understanding your need, the best approach would be to set the defaults at the database level. If a record is saved with a null value for that attribute, it will automatically get the default value set at the database level.  The end result is much cleaner code and no extra processing needs during data load as the default is there at rest.

In the migration, for example, `$table->string(‘favorite_color’)->default(‘Blue’);`  , as described at https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#column-modifiers

Would this solve your need? If not, it probably means your need is contextual, and that this default doesn’t always need to apply. Think critically about that context and what it represents. It might indicate a difference in data which might cause further problems down the road.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi. No you have not understood. The default values are already in the migrations. The question is simple. Obtain the default values of each column of a table, using Eloquent or DB. Why is it simple? He assures me that he does not forget any column with default value, in tables like many columns of these characteristics, and in addition to the development phase, in addition to allowing me to programmatically design some element constraint design, without repeating dozens of lines of code. Best regargds